# Testthat - test if file can be loaded and use it for further tests

Tags: r, testthat

I want to test a dataset using testthat and as a first test, I want to test if can be loaded. I do this as follow:

```
test_that( "Data can be loaded",
           {
             expect_error(
               nd <<- read_feather(DATAFILE),
               regexp = NA
             )
           }
)
```

As you ca see, I have to use the dreaded `<<-` to be able to access `nd` in the following tests:

```
test_that(
  "Names are OK",
  {
    expect_named( nd, nd_names )
  }
)
```

Is there a better alternative for using the `<<-` in tyhis case?

Comment: maybe read it in within testthat.R rather than in the individual test-00*-*.R files?

Comment: Sure - that would work. But I want to wrap the loading into a expect_  function.

Comment: Write a function that runs `expect_error`, then returns `nd`. Call the function when you need `nd`. Bonus points for memoizing the function so the data is loaded, and test is run, only once.

Comment: This should also work, but it seems quite involved to do this if one wants to read the data only once.

Answer (score 1):

First to the test. Then load it again

`test_that( "Data can be loaded",
           {
             expect_error(
               read_feather(DATAFILE),
               regexp = NA
             )
           }
)
nd <- read_feather(DATAFILE)
test_that(
  "Names are OK",
  {
    expect_named( nd, nd_names )
  }
)`

Comment: Two problems: If there is an error in the reading of the file, it get's thrown in the second read again (which I want to avoid) and 2) I have to d it twice which is not really an option if one is dealing with large files or many files which need to be tested.

Comment: I see two more options: 1) use `assign()` to store `nd` in an environment. 2) combine both tests in the same `test_that()` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible pattern (untested!) using the `memoise` package:

```
load_nd <- function () {
  expect_error(
        nd <- read_feather(DATAFILE), 
        regexp = NA)
  nd
}

load_nd <- memoise::memoise(load_nd)
```

Now call the function whenever you need the data. You can define the function in `testthat.R`, or in a helper file (name starts with `helper`) in the `testthat` directory, or just at the start of a given test file.

Comment: OK that should work. But it sounds to complicated and adds a new dependency only for that.

Comment: So don't memoise, and call the function in the top level of your test files. It doesn't look complicated to me: it is a function containing two commands.

Comment: But in this case, I don't need the expect as it is not included in the results of the test in the same format.

Comment: Oy vey! I am out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.